# Git hook to produce Github "Create Pull Request" link in terminal like Bitbucket Does

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

One of the things I find very handy about Bitbucket is when you push a new branch up to a repo hosted in Bitbucket, it prints out (to the terminal screen) a URL that you can hit to create a PR from that branch you just pushed.  Ex:

```
$ git push origin someBranch
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 313 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for someBranch:
remote:   https://bitbucket.mydomain.com/projects/PRO/repos/someRepo/compare/commits?sourceBranch=refs/heads/someBranch
remote:
To ssh://bitbucket.mydomain.com:7999/pro/somerepo.git
f6718d4..410cbcb  someBranch -> someBranch
```

I find this to be a *huge* timesaver over going to Bitbucket, navigating to the repo, finding the "Create Pull Request" button, etc.  As such, I'd like something similar for when I'm working with a repo hosted on Github -- after a push of a new branch, have it print out to the terminal a URL I can hit to get to the create PR screen on Github.  Anyone know of anything like this?

I know there's a CLI for Github with a `pull-request` command, but that prompts you for your password every time which is very annoying, and TBH I like to look at the diff in the UI before actually creating the PR.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Created my own local hook that works well enough for my needs.  Add this as a `pre-push` hook to your local clone of a repo:

```
#!/bin/sh

branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
userRepo=$(git remote -v | grep fetch | awk '{print $2}' | grep "github.com" | cut -d':' -f2 | rev | cut -c5- | rev)

if [ -n "$userRepo" ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "Create PR at: https://github.com/$userRepo/compare/$branch?expand=1"
    echo ""
fi
```

Example output:

```
$ git push origin testouthooks

Create PR at: https://github.com/pzelnip/dotfiles/compare/testouthooks?expand=1

Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 284 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To github.com:pzelnip/dotfiles.git
f7c29b8..f6f9347  testouthooks -> testouthooks
```

I can then hit that url emitted to land on the create pull request page in Github with the branch I just pushed as the source branch.

This isn't quite equivalent to Bitbucket, as it's run locally (the Bitbucket one is run on the remote) so it's not as intelligent (ex: it still emits the URL even if the push resulted in no changes on the remote, etc).  But it suits my need of "when I push to a Github repo, I can click a link from my terminal window to get to the create PR page in Github".

Comment: It works well but why do you use grep "github.com"? It seems to do the job without it.

Comment: Because I often work with repos from Bitbucket.com as well, and for those repos when I do a push I don't want this hook to spit out the echo stuff.

Comment: `https://github.com/$userRepo/compare/$base...$branch?expand=1` will specify the base branch (target) for the PR. (Where is this documented?)

Comment: Bummer, my gitbash lacks `rev`. I need to find a way to replace that part

Comment: `https://github.com/$org/$repo/pull/new/$branch` seems to be the new URL

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this (on gitbash, with no `rev` and using the more recent bitbucket):

```
#!/bin/sh

bbHost='bitbucket.org'
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)    
userRepo=$(git remote -v | grep fetch | awk '{print $2}' | grep "$bbHost" | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/.git//g")

echo "hey!"
echo $userRepo

if [ -n "$userRepo" ]
then
    echo ""
    echo "Create PR at: https://$bbHost/$userRepo/pull-requests/new?source=$branch"
    echo ""
    # remove this line if you don't want the browser to open
    start chrome https://$bbHost/$userRepo/pull-requests/new?source=$branch
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The [pre-push git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) actual provides 2 arguments you can make use of, using these I came up with the simpler version below.

- $1 gives the remote, e.g. 'origin' - not useful here
- $2 is the url. It's suffixed by .git, which we need to strip out with sed, using 2g skips the first hit (so we don't convert .github.com to .hub.com)

```
#!/bin/sh
url=$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.git//2g')
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

echo ""
echo "Create PR at: $url/compare/$branch?expand=1"
echo ""
```

I also work with **Azure DevOps** repos, this is the version that works there. In this case the url is fine as is, but we need to convert forward slashes to '%2F' in the branch name:

```
#!/bin/sh
url="$2"
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's./.%2F.g')

echo ""
echo "Create PR at: $url/pullrequestcreate?sourceRef=$branch"
echo ""
```